# GetFileInformationByHandle() for stdio file handles

Tags: c, winapi, stdio

Is there any way to use GetFileInformationByHandle() with stdio file handles allocated by fopen()? Using fstat() with fileno() is not sufficient for my purposes because I need to get some Windows-specific information that is not part of struct stat so I'm wondering whether there is any way to feed an stdio FILE* handle to GetFileInformationByHandle()?

Comment: make file handle by `CreateFile`.

Comment: But this doesn't allow me to use the stdio file handle as the source. It wants to have a filename. I'd like to avoid establishing a second file handle next to the stdio file handle. I want to know whether or not it's possible to somehow access the Windows file handle stored inside the FILE* stdio handle to feed it to GetFileInformationByHandle(). Visual C stdio has all kinds of Microsoft extensions so maybe there's an extension for this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`_fileno()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6wbdhx.aspx) to get the file number (no I don't know why Microsoft added the `_`, other than for "ISO C++ conformance") and then [`_get_osfhandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks2530z6.aspx) to go from file number to `HANDLE`. I don't remember offhand why the msvcrt uses file numbers instead of tying a `FILE` directly to a `HANDLE` (but I think it's for POSIX compatibility?).