# Attributes For Standard In/Out/Err on Windows

Tags: file, winapi

Consider the following:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <io.h>

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[]) {
    HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    //HANDLE handle = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(_fileno(stdout)); //or this; doesn't matter

    BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION info;
    BOOL okay = GetFileInformationByHandle(handle,&info);
    assert(okay!=0);

    return 0;
}
```

The assert in this program fails, with [`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) reporting that the file handle is invalid.  This makes it impossible to extract [attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117(v=vs.85).aspx) from `info`.

However, this is the recommended approach.  For example ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21070042/688624)), ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347796/getfileinformationbyhandle-for-stdio-file-handles)).  It's worth noting that it *does* work if it's a handle to a physically backed `FILE*` (e.g. created with `fopen(...)`).

**How can I get attributes for std in/out/err streams on Windows?**

Comment: *"this is the recommended approach"* - The recommended approach to solve *which* problem? You never explained, which problem you are trying to solve. Just that your proposed solution apparently won't do.

Answer (score 1):

attributes ( `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_*` ) exist only for files on FileSystem device. when in/out/err stream not redirected to file on FileSystem - no any attributes in this case. even pipes not have attributes. so in general - you can not got this. what you mean under attributes ?

Comment: This is all actually a convoluted way of trying to find whether a given stream is readable/writable/appendable.

Comment: @imallett - not for windows

Comment: @imallett, the attributes won't tell you anything about the handle's access rights anyway.  Even in the case of a file handle, the fact that the file's read-only bit isn't set (for example) doesn't necessarily mean that *this particular handle* is writable.  (Heck, it doesn't even mean that the file is writable; the ACL might not allow it.)